# implementation of an Moore Automaton in digital electronics

Tags: fsm

in the wikipedia article about Moore Automatons it is said, that clocked digital circuits are a form of moore automatons.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine#Mechanism

how about the other way around. how is an arbitrary moore automaton implementet in digital electronics, are there any rules how to build the circuit. or is this never done? just wondering...

Answer (score 1):

First you find out all possible (and impossible) input states and corresponding output states of the moore automaton. It is important that you have some reasonable output states for impossible input states, because in real life there may be interference that changes the state of bits to something unexpected.

There are several methods how the logic can be built. For small number of states one can use [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). For bigger systems there are other means. Maybe the simplest method to implement logic is to store the state transfers into memory by using input state as address and output state as data.